# iphone - distribution certificate not showing in keychain access

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I need to upload an app. I have built to the app store. I've been following the walkthroughs and have got stuck on the bit when i download the distribution certificate.
[image]
my provisioning profile is listed under the provisioning profile column, ive just blanked it out. when i download the certificate, i double click it, keychain access opens and my certificate is listed in the 'certificates' tab, but not the 'my certificates' tab with no dropdown to show a private key has been created. Is there something Im missing? ive been through 4 different walkthroughs all saying i need to just double click the certificate.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging by the Expiration Date this certificate was created a while ago.

If you are using a different computer, or simply do not have the private key saved for any reason you will not be able to use this certificate. Basically, you have 2 options:

1. Find the original private key that was used to create this certificate and import it to keychain.
2. Simply revoke it and create a new one, don't worry, it will not affect your ability to deploy on the App Store. Just remember to recreate distribution provisioning profiles as well.

Comment: needed to revoke the certificate

Comment: I made dist cert from my Mac, after download and install, i see private key & cert in different section under login, i cannot expand the cert which usually should be expandable showing private key. How can i resolve it?

Answer (score 44):

Restart XCode should fix the problem. Wasted 2 hours because of this error.

Comment: You saved me from a minor headache

Comment: The keychain asks for access once every Xcode open, it seems, so I'm assuming it does a single check instead of a real time sync.

Comment: Yes I think so :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Teddi.

Comment: Unbelievable, what a fix. It actually helped

Comment: so many times all you have to do is restart xcode, but it may take you hours to find out. Seriously, Apple?

Answer (score 4):

In XCode Organizer, under Library->Provisioning Profiles, try refreshing the list by clicking the refresh icon on the bottom right corner. It will connect to your developer account and retrieve the profiles again.

Answer (score 2):

If you have not added certificate manualy try check Apple Developer account.
Sometimes limit reached and XCode does not notice about it :(

In case you created and added (manualy) certificate to keychain - just restart XCode and try again.